# LDP based VPLS between Cisco IOS XE and Juniper MX

Tags: cisco, juniper, mpls, vpls

im struggeling in setting up LDP based VPLS in a Cisco/Juniper mixed vendor environment.

The configuration is currently running between two Cisco Boxes, but i have to migrate on side to Juniper.

this is the current configuration:

Cisco ASR1k:

```
l2 vfi VPLS-1839 manual 
vpn id 1839
bridge-domain 1839
neighbor x.x.x.x encapsulation mpls

interface GigabitEthernet0/0/3
 no ip address
 negotiation auto
 service instance 1839 ethernet
  encapsulation untagged
  rewrite ingress tag push dot1q 1839 symmetric
  bridge-domain 1839
```

Juniper MX:

```
routing-instances {
    VPLS-1839 {
        instance-type vpls;
        vlan-id none;
        interface xe-1/1/0.0;
        protocols {
            vpls {
                no-tunnel-services;
                vpls-id 1839;
                neighbor x.x.x.x;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

a "show vpls connections" on the Juniper shows following output.

```
Instance: VPLS-1839
  VPLS-id: 1839
    Neighbor                  Type  St     Time last up          # Up trans
    x.x.x.x(vpls-id 1839) rmt OL
```

OL is described as "no outgoing label", but i don't have an idea what this message is trying to tell me.

LDP is running on alle core-facing interfaces and the lo0.0. MPLS address-family is also present on all interfaces.

Any idea how to isolate the cause of this issue?
Thanks in advance for any hints.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No outgoing label indicates that Junos doesn't have a label for the loopback you are targeting on the Cisco (your x.x.x.x address)

Confirm the following:

1. Your NNI interface from the Juniper has `family mpls` configured
2. Under `protocols mpls` you have the NNI `interface` defined
3. Under `protocols ldp` you have the NNI `interface` defined
4. Under `protocols ldp` you also have the loopback `interface` defined
5. Finally, use `show ldp session` or `show route table inet.3` and  confirm that the far-end loopback is visible in the list

Comment: Hi Benjamin, Thanks for this reply.
- 1 MPLS is enabled on the core-facing interfaces
- 2 core-facing-interfaces are defined in protocols MPLS, visible under 'show mpls interface'
- 3 core-facing-interfaces are defined in protocols LDP, visible under 'show ldp interface'
- 4 Lo0.0 is also defined under in protocols LDP
- 5 Loopback IP of remote PE router is visible under  'show route table inet.3'
But VPLS neighbor is still OL

Comment: It seems that there is a broken LSP but all MPLS based L3VPN Services are working fine between the boxes.

Comment: Are the CE-facing interfaces in the VPLS up?

Comment: It is up on the Cisco box, but down on the Juniper. But setting 'connectivity-type permanent' under 'protocols vpls' still shows the OL state.

Comment: okay cool - yes, that's what I was getting at.  To me it still sounds like something is not right with your underlying MPLS configuration.  Especially if you're only getting one-way setup.  Is the Juniper connecting to any P nodes before it gets to the Cisco?  Have these all got MPLS configured on their interfaces?